Не работает http аутентификация в zabbix 6.x
Установил zabbix сервер 6-ой версии. Настраивал на рабочих машин, дошли руки до аутентификации, необходимо дать доступ коллегам для удобства через http, как было на предыдущей 5-ой версии. Пользователи заранее созданы с необходимыми правами.
Только она не работает. В чем может быть ошибка? Просмотрел все конфиги, настроено строго с документацией.
Пишет:

You are not logged in Session terminated, re-login, please. Incorrect
user name or password or account is temporarily blocked.

